# nodetool with Java 8u331 returns "URISyntaxException: 'Malformed IPv6 address at index 7: rmi://[127.0.0.1]:7199'"

Tags: java, cassandra

Why does running `nodetool` return the following exception?

```
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - \
  URISyntaxException: 'Malformed IPv6 address at index 7: rmi://[127.0.0.1]:7199'.
```

This question is commonly reported by Cassandra users after upgrading Java on servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Root cause

The URL parser for JNDI providers which includes RMI (used by JMX) has been improved in Oracle Java 8u331 and brackets are only allowed around IPv6 addresses ([JDK-8278972](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u331-relnotes.html)).

Attempts to run `nodetool` with newer Java versions breaks because the host in the RMI URL is enclosed in square brackets (from [NodeProbe.java](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0.3/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/tools/NodeProbe.java#L108) class):

```
    private static final String fmtUrl = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://[%s]:%d/jmxrmi";
```

### Workarounds

**OPTION 1** - Add the "legacy" parsing flag when running `nodetool`, for example:

```
$ nodetool -Dcom.sun.jndi.rmiURLParsing=legacy status
```

**OPTION 2** - Specify the hostname with an IPv6 subnet prefix, for example:

```
$ nodetool -h ::FFFF:127.0.0.1 status
```

### Solution

This issue has been addressed in Apache Cassandra 3.0.27, 3.11.13, 4.0.4 and 4.1 releases ([CASSANDRA-17581](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-17581)).

Upgrade to the latest patch release to fix the issue in your cluster. Cheers!

---

Republished from [DataStax Community](https://community.datastax.com/questions/13764/).

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!